# Send buffer with IP packet through RAW socket

Tags: c, sockets

Lets say that I have a buffer with IP message (SYN / ACK or whatever), all headers - TCP and IP are filled and so on. I want to send it through raw socket.

When I execute this

```
void send_ip(void* data, u16_t len) {
std::cout << "begine  of send_ip" << std::endl;
int s;
struct sockaddr_in dst_addr;
if ((s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) < 0) {
  perror("error:");
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
const int hdrincl = 1;
setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &hdrincl, sizeof(hdrincl));

dst_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
dst_addr.sin_port = 6667;
inet_aton("172.17.9.71", &dst_addr.sin_addr);
std::cout << "before send in  send_ip, len = " << (u16_t)len << std::endl;

if (sendto(s, data, len, 0,
  (struct sockaddr *)&dst_addr, (socklen_t)sizeof(dst_addr)) < 0) {
perror("sendto ERROR :");

    }
    else{

  }

}
```

I get

```
sendto ERROR :: Invalid argument
```

When I change it to

```
  s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP)
```

And take away

```
setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &hdrincl, sizeof(hdrincl));
```

I get OK for sending, but in Wireshark there is a message

```
110539  1059.796163000  172.17.9.210    172.17.9.71 TCP 78  65535 > 65535 [SYN, RST,     
Reserved] Seq=0 Win=1, bogus TCP header length (0, must be at least 20)
```

So the message goesn't go to the server. What do I do wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: You must fill in the TCP and IP headers, in the RAW sockets before sending a packet.

Comment: And if I have ALREADY filled message? Lets say I got packet from application that makes IP packets and want to send it ?